# Windows Server 2003 R2, SMB, alternative port?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2003-r2

How can I setup SMB on my server to use an alternative port? I'm attempting to use something other than port 445.

Comment: why? hopefully not for security purposes?

Comment: Whenever I'm on the road, some ISPs block 445 which means I cannot access my website folder when the server is at work.

Comment: ok that explains things a little, do you have other users or is it just you?

Comment: Other users too, but they never found this website.

Comment: there is a lot wrong with what you are doing and something sounds kinda fishy about it when you say "but they never found this website" what are you saying? Are you editing files that are part of website?  If so then you should be using webdav more then likely. then you can access the files like a normal directory using port 80.

Comment: @tonyroth: I think by "this website" the OP means *this* website, i.e., serverfault.com.

Comment: Using smb over the public internet is a Very Bad Idea.  Maybe explain what you are really trying to accomplish and we can suggest a more secure and reliable way. ISPs block port 445 for a reason.

Comment: All I need is for coworkers and I to use our SMB shares from anywhere using an alternative port, I do understand it's bad to use it externally, but all of us are fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to muck around with SMB on the server, you should investigate using a VPN.  Windows Server includes both DirectAccess and Routing and Remote Access, either of which should be able to solve your problem.  Your networking equipment may also have VPN support.

Comment: VPN has never worked for us, so we just stopped trying with it.